# Understanding what mono memory is used where

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to understand how to use the profiler to inspect c# objects that are not related to the scene. In my application, after parsing a bunch of xml and creating a bunch of objects that persist via a static dictionary, I can see the mono memory value jump up on the profiler. However I cannot seem to see the breakdown of what memory is where, how many instances of objects exists etc. It would seem the profiler only knows about GameObjects and mono behaviours. Is this accurate?

Answer (score 0):

if your main concern is to see the memory size of your static dictionary, you can do so by using the profiler class:

public static int GetRuntimeMemorySize(Object o);

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Profiler.GetRuntimeMemorySize.html

you can also use the profiler class functions:

public static void BeginSample(string name, Object targetObject);

public static void EndSample();

to profile a piece of code with a custom label.

Comment: That is interesting, but I am more looking for counts so I can find leaked objects or spot trouble areas.